# $\iint_{D} e^{\sin x \cos y} dA$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I have a double integral

$$\iint_{D} e^{\sin x \cos y} dA$$

where $D$ is the disk with center the origin and radius $3$.

My guess would be to estimate the integral by a change of variables technique, but I can't seem to know where to start from. Maybe I should perform a trigonometric substitution?

Any hints and solutions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should try the substitution and post how far you get?

Comment: Substitute and use the Jacobian!

Comment: Closest answer I could find: We know $-1\leq\sin(x)\leq 1$ and $-1\leq\cos(y)\leq 1$, this means $e^{-1}\leq e^{\sin(x)\cos(y)}\leq e$ Then we have that $\frac{9\pi}{e}\leq \iint_{D}e^{\sin(x)\cos(y)}dA \leq 9\pi\,e$.

Comment: Thank u @BenjaminMoss, I figured it out already, just had to use 1 of the properties of double integrals

Comment: @krszyoscezio can you please post your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the properties of double integrals

If $ {m \le f(x,y) \le M} $ for all $ (x,y) $ in $D$, then
$$ mA(D) \le \iint_D f(x,y)dA \le MA(D) $$

We could estimate the given integral $ \iint_D e^{\sin x\ \cos y} dA$, where $D$ is the circle with radius $3$

As Benjamin Moss noted above, $-1 \leq \sin(x)\cos(y)\leq 1$

Now we can proceed to $$ e^{-1} \le e^{\sin x\ \cos y} \leq e ,$$

where $m=e^{-1}$ and $M=e$.

$A(D)$ which is the area of the circle has a formula of $A=\pi r^2$

Therefore, our final estimation would be $$ {(9\pi)\over {e}} \le \iint_D e^{\sin x  \cos y}  dA \le 9\pi e$$

Comment: It's a decent start but we need to figure out how to convert $e^{\sin(x)\cos(y)}$ into a form we can actually integrate